# How to use cross_cal_score for MNIST dataset? How to fix: "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

How to use cross_cal_score for MNIST dataset? Shapes between the output of my model and the *y* in *cross_cal_score* are incompatible.

I would like to perform k-fold cross validation for MNIST dataset (an example in *DEEP LEARNING: FROM BASICS TO PRACTICE*).

Here is the softmax layer of the model(10 outputs):

`model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))`

And I use *'cross_val_score'* and keras wrapper *'KerasClassifier'*

```
# make a model and wrap it up for scikit-learn
kc_model = KerasClassifier(model=make_model,
                           number_of_layers=2, neurons_per_layer=32, optimizer='adam',
                           epochs=100, batch_size=256, verbose=1)

# create cross-validator
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator=kc_model, X=X_train, y=original_y_train, cv=kfold, verbose=1)
```

After running the code I get a warning advising the incompatible shapes between the output of my model and the *y* in *cross_cal_score*. because the *original_y_train* is NOT a one-hot version.

`ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible`

How can I perform k-fold cross-validation for a classifier?

Here is the my code below:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# convert to floating-point
X_train = keras_backend.cast_to_floatx(X_train)
number_of_pixels = 28 * 28

# normalization: scale data to range[0, 1]
X_train /= 255

# save the original y_train and y_test
original_y_train = y_train

# replace label data with one-hot encoded versions
number_of_classes = 1 + max(np.append(y_train, y_test))

# reshape samples to 2D grid, one line per image
X_train = X_train.reshape([X_train.shape[0], number_of_pixels])


def make_model(number_of_layers=2, neurons_per_layer=32, optimizer='adam', dropout_ratio=0.2):
    # create a model
    model = Sequential()
    # the first layer
    model.add(Dense(neurons_per_layer, activation='relu', input_shape=[number_of_pixels], kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_ratio))
    # the following layer
    for i in range(number_of_layers - 1):
        model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_ratio))
    # the softmax layer
    model.add(Dense(number_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


# make a model and wrap it up for scikit-learn
kc_model = KerasClassifier(model=make_model,
                           number_of_layers=2, neurons_per_layer=32, optimizer='adam',
                           epochs=100, batch_size=256, verbose=1)

# create cross-validator
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator=kc_model, X=X_train, y=original_y_train, cv=kfold, verbose=1)
```

And the warning:

```
Epoch 1/100
Epoch 1/100
Epoch 1/100
Epoch 1/100
Epoch 1/100
Epoch 1/100
Epoch 1/100
Epoch 1/100
Epoch 1/100
Epoch 1/100
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:    4.1s finished
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\keras\cross_val_model.py", line 65, in <module>
    results = cross_val_score(estimator=kc_model, X=X_train, y=original_y_train, cv=kfold, verbose=1)
  File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 515, in cross_val_score
    cv_results = cross_validate(
  File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 285, in cross_validate
    _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
  File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 367, in _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures
    raise ValueError(all_fits_failed_message)
ValueError: 
All the 10 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 686, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 1494, in fit
    super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 762, in fit
    self._fit(
  File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 931, in _fit
    self._fit_keras_model(
  File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 526, in _fit_keras_model
    hist = self.model_.fit(x=X, y=y, **fit_args)
  File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\18621\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filesuem1zgk.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 890, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 139, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 243, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1787, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\18621\anaconda3\envs\TensorFLow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5119, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 0):

oh, I replaced 'categorical_crossentropy' with 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' and I succeeded.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).